# Math needed to study Navier-Stokes existence and smoothness problem

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

This is [Navier-Stokes existence and smoothness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier-Stokes_existence_and_smoothness) problem.

I think the main problem is that I am not familiar with the mathematics of the Navier-Stokes existence smoothness problem.

- What kind of math do I need to learn to understand what the problem (of Navier-Stokes existence smoothness) actually is!?
- How to understand math of Navier-Stokes existence and smoothness problem?

Comment: All you really need to know is what a (strong) solution to a PDE means and what smoothness means.

Comment: do you understand what is the physical meaning of each term in the Navier-Stokes equation ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes,
I can understand its physical meaning.

Comment: then I think you need to know a bit on : Fourier series, $L^2,l^2$ Hilbert spaces, $L^p$ spaces, Schwartz space, (tempered) distributions and their Fourier transform, solving PDE by considering Sobolev spaces and using the functional analysis terminology, and that's all

Comment: https://www.quantamagazine.org/20150721-famous-fluid-equations-are-incomplete/

Answer (score 2):

See the answers to these MO questions (and the hyperlinks contained therein):

[Surveys on Navier Stokes Equations and its physical implications](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26223)

[Why don't existence and uniqueness for the Boltzmann equation imply the same for Navier-Stokes?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18539)

[Is there a mathematically precise definition of turbulence for solutions of Navier-Stokes?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27805)